# Shouldn't it be "based on fantasy"?

Tags: prepositions

> Director Barry Levinson said on MLB Network's "Costas at the Movies" in 2013 that while the film is **based in** fantasy, "through the years, these things which are outlandish actually [happen] ... like Kirk Gibson hitting the home run and limping around the bases ... Curt Schilling with the blood on the sock in the World Series." ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Natural_(film)))

Why is the preposition "in" used here? I thought "base in" can only refer to someone/something being *based in a place*. Is this usage in the Wiki article correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of **based in** in can also be used (perhaps only idiomatically) in a synonymous way with **rooted in**.

Specifically, it can be juxtaposed with both *fantasy* and *reality*.

From an article called ["I’m in love with a woman in work. Should I tell her?"](https://www.irishtimes.com/life-and-style/health-family/i-m-in-love-with-a-woman-in-work-should-i-tell-her-1.3523984) in *The Irish Times*:

> So what you feel right now? That is not love. That is want and infatuation and obsession, and it’s not based in reality; it’s based in fantasy.

You might argue that **based in** *fantasy* is short for *based in a fantasy* ***world***, but that doesn't explain the use of **based in** *reality*—because it's certainly not short for *based in a reality* ***world*** or *based in a real* ***world***. Both *fantasy* and *reality* are being used here as concepts rather than shortened forms of a countable noun.

---

We understand *based in reality* in the same way that we understand *rooted in reality*.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [**rooted in**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rooted%20in):

> : formed, made, or developed by using (something) as a basis • Her opinions are deeply *rooted in* her faith. • a dance *rooted in* African tradition

In an equivalent sense, **based in** does not need to refer to a physical location.

---

In fact, if you look at the Merriam-Webster definition of [**based**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/based), it doesn't refer to "a *base* of operation" but to an adjective:

> : having a specified type of base or basis • a soundly *based* argument • I realized that his technique was psychoanalytically *based*. —Robert Klitzman

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of this quote is that when the author says "based in fantasy", he is implicitly saying "based in a fantasy world".

This would satisfy the requirement for the phrase 'based in' to reference a place.